# What is the minimum salary possible in a Her Majesty's Government's Department's job?

Tags: united-kingdom, public-sector-compensation

[Government of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_United_Kingdom)

> The Government of the United Kingdom, domestically referred to as Her Majesty's Government, is the central government of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.

[Ministers and departments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_United_Kingdom#Ministers_and_departments)

> As of 2019, there are around 120 government ministers supported by 560,000 civil servants and other staff working in the 25 ministerial departments and their executive agencies. There are also an additional 20 non-ministerial departments with a range of further responsibilities.

What is the minimum salary possible in a [Her Majesty's Government's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_United_Kingdom) Department's job?

Think of supervisor, clerks, cleaning personnel, guard, anything. Which "pay grade" gets the lowest salary and how much is it per month?

I do not need information of casual, contractual employees. By employee, I mean someone working till retirement unless of course they retire before retirement.

Optional note. Special allowance given to any particular department like (say, police, just example) may be ignored for the time being. I assume it is given to particular departments. The police cleaner might get some extra allowance to maintain uniform. While, a cleaner from other ministries might not get it. It's an imaginary example.

Comment: You seem to be having problems defining your question. You originally asked about both the US and UK and about the Olympics. If you make major changes to your question, please close the original question and ask a new one.

Comment: @doneal24 When making changes to a question there is no reason to close it and reask it if there are no answers to it. The concern about making major changes to a question is about invalidating answers and as there are no answers on this question there is no concern about the scope of the question changing.

Comment: @JoeW The question has been re-written so much that it has little resemblance to the original post. Perhaps the OP should withdraw the question until he can ask a coherent question. Downvotes have also been based on the original question and are part of the response.

Comment: @doneal24 And what exactly is the problem? This question has no answers that would be invalidated by the change. I would also say this is a good example of taking a bad question and making it better based on the feedback received. There is no reason to close/delete a question that can be salvaged with good edits especially if it has not received any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks about "governmental job" but excludes "contractors" etc. Now a lot of the lowest skill jobs, like office cleaning, will be done by contractors. So if by "governmental job" you mean actual civil servants, who are in salaried positions, the answer is about £15,500

The civil service is divided up into [different grades](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/grade-structures-civil-service), from Administrative assistant (at the bottom) to Permanent Secretary (at the top)  Some departments don't use the same names for the grades, so an Administrative assistant is called "Grade F" at the Ministery of Justice.

Each department is able to set its own pay grades, according to market conditions and the need to set pay at a level to attract skilled staff.  At the lower end, [an Administrative Assistant (the lowest pay grade) in HMRC or the MOJ could earn as little as £15,500](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/civil-service-pay), such a pay grade would be for roles that tend to comprise administrative support and operational delivery roles such as caterers, and perhaps cleaners.  It doesn't include people in a training context or, for example, an apprenticeship. The actual take-home pay may be less for part-time workers.

Comment: *Now a lot of the lowest skill jobs, like office cleaning, will be done by contractors.* Is there a scope for someone to do that job till his 60s? Otherwise, do you mean Administrative Assistant is the lowest category of job in the UK which is parmanent in nature?

Comment: Well you won't stay on 15,000 for the whole of your career!  Pay is dependent on skills and experience, so will naturally rise.  15,000 is an entry level.

Comment: As always I like your answer, in India the lowest category of jobs are that of Peons and Chowkidars (kindly Google search). No matter how low the salary, but it's parmanent in nature. No scope of posts  lower than Administrative Assistant in the UK to be parmanent in nature?

Comment: Do you mean Administrative assistant is at the lowest category of parmanent Government jobs?

Comment: An administrative assistant would be a "permanent contract".  But one would naturally progress through your career.  But, yes "Adminstrative Assistant" is the lowest category in the UK civil service.

Comment: I have to accept your answer now because the post of administrative assistant is of parmanent nature and is in the lowest category of such.

Comment: Peon = "office boy/girl"  That would be a training position in the UK. Chowkidar=watchman/woman  That would likely be a Adminstrative Assistant grade role, or (more likely) contracted out.

Comment: Both the posts of Peons and Chowkidars in India are of parmanent in nature. Usually the eligibility criteria is grade 8 or grade 10 (high school). Regardless it is a parmanent job, one can do till his 60.

Answer (score 2):

### "What is the minimum salary possible in a Her Majesty's Government's Department's job?"

The minimum salary possible for any job (including in a government department) is [£4.30 per hour](https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates) for apprentices aged under 19 or aged 19+ and in their first year of an apprenticeship. Technically a lower salary is possible for children under school leaving age (in which case there is no minimum), but you are unlikely to find such children working in a government department.

Comment: *Technically a lower salary is possible for children under school leaving age (in which case there is no minimum),* Is there a scope for that child to work in the same place till his 60s?

Comment: @Gary2 Is there a scope for anyone to work in the same place until their 60's? People will get hired into a position and it will change and grow over time. It is pretty much impossible for someone to stay in the same place for an entire career either they will move up over time or lost the position due to incompetence.  Also I am pretty sure a child worker won't meet your full time position requirement but an apprentice would.

Comment: @Gary2 Just be clear, I wasn't implying that someone who starts work as a child can be paid under minimum wage if they stay in the job. Mininum wage requirements will apply as soon as they are of school leaving age.

Comment: @JoeW *People will get hired into a position and it will change and grow over time.* That is okay when these two conditions are met: 1. He must be able to work there till his retirement period (whatever it's 60, 65 years old) 2. It is the lowest possible that a person earn right after he starts working. *It is pretty much impossible for someone to stay in the same place for an entire career either they will move up over time* yes, okay. Promotion is okay. *or lost the position due to incompetence.* this is a rare case scenario which may not be considered.

Comment: *Also I am pretty sure a child worker won't meet your full time position requirement but an apprentice would.* I have excluded apprenticeship. Someone is a high school graduate, is of 18 or whatever, he is eligible to the lowest category of the job, that is what I want.

Comment: @JBentley *Mininum wage requirements will apply as soon as they are of school leaving age.* That would be applicable provided he can continue working without any educational or further training requirements till he reaches 60 or 65 or 70 whatever age it is that he work maximum.

Comment: @Gary2 Those apprentices all high school graduates and over the age of 18, and in fact over the age of 19 according to the answer. An apprentice position is and will always be a full time position. I think the issue here is how jobs work in India is completely different than how jobs work in the UK/US. In those countries there is no position that you can start after school and still be working for the same pay/position by the time you are 60. All the jobs you are asking about increase in pay and position the longer you stay at the job and the more experience you get.

Comment: @Gary2 There is no way the pay someone would be receiving at the age of 18 is the same as they would be receiving at the age of 60 when they are nearing retirement.

Comment: @JoeW yes agreed. I agreed before too that promotion, yearly increments, etc. happen. However, they must be doing the same thing because they haven't passed high school or so. An administrative assistant I believe needs to be well educated something at least like a bachelor's degree.

Comment: @Gary2 I think you are misunderstanding something in the UK it would be very unlikely for someone without a high school degree to be working in the government. In a country where pretty much everyone has a high school degree trying to find a job without one is very hard and getting a government job is impossible. I would expect for a lot of those jobs they want education past high school.

Comment: @JoeW *I would expect for a lot of those jobs they want education past high school* I don't understand why a cleaner needs to pass high school. Again, isn't it possible for someone to keep becoming a cleaner (for a ministry of the Government) till his 60 or 65 provided he gets an yearly increment and doesn't get fired because he is diligent?

Comment: If no, are cleaning, home security, etc. always undertaken by contractual companies? The contractual company is more likely to be in touch in the ministry than the persons working with the company?

Comment: @Gary2 A Janitor is going to be a contractor and not a full time employee but even still a high school diploma is pretty much required since so few people don't graduate. It seems you keep comparing the standards in India that don't apply in the UK.

Comment: @JoeW okay. Thanks for the extensive support. Seems I got the answer. An administrative assistant is the lowest parmanent post in Her Majesty's Government. This is odd in many ways. When I think of a office, I can't imagine an administrative assistant needing to do many things like : 1. Carrying the files to the senior 2. Typing, printing, getting it signed, scanning and uploading. Many more... Well, anyways things are going on smoothly so looks good.

Comment: @Gary2 That sounds like what a bad one would do, a good one does so much more than that it isn't funny.